# Expected value of sum of x random balls without replacement

Tags: combinatorics, expected-value

I've been trying to create a value function for an AI action and have been stuck for a while now. This question is more of a generalization of the original since I thought it was interesting.

Suppose there are *n* balls in a bag, with each assigned a number from 1-*i* for some finite
*i*, and you draw *x* balls without replacement, where *x* < *n*. Is there a way excluding brute force to find the expected value of the sum of the numbers on the drawn balls?

So far I have the following:

Let $X_i$ be the random variable for the $i$th ball drawn.

$
E[X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_x] = E[X_1] + E[X_2] + \dots + E[X_x] =
\sum_{i=k}^nE[X_k]$

Where $X_i$ is the expected value of the avg of a subset size $n-k+1$

Except now I'm sort of stuck on where to go besides brute-forcing the problem.

Comment: Expected total equal average value times the number of terms.  What is the average value of the elements of $\{1,2,\cdots,i\}$?  Since no information is given about the distribution of the values from $\{1,2,\cdots,i\}$ to the $n$ balls, you can **ignore** the fact that there are $n$ balls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's always going to be the mean value of all the balls times the number of balls drawn.